# LINQ and deferred execution when comparing with NULL

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing some optimization of DB access and have been wondering about the deferred execution. I have already learnt that `SomeQueriable.Count()` is much more efficient than `SomeQueriable.ToList().Count` or `SomeQueriable.ToArray().Length`, since it uses native DB COUNT method.

But what about the search result itself? When I want to compare the query result to null, is there a difference between `SomeQueriable == null` and `SomeQueriable.ToList() == null`?

Moreover, is using `SomeQueriable.Count()` safe, or do I have to always check against null? In other words, is

```
if (SomeQueriable == null || SomeQueriable.Count() == 0)
```

the same as

```
if (SomeQueriable.Count() == 0)
```

or will the latter cause an exception, when no records are found?

Comment: If `SomeQueriable` is an actual query and not explicitly assigned a null value you do not have to check for null.

Comment: Sure there is a difference, because `SomeQueriable.ToList() == null` will throw a NRE when `SomeQueriable` is `Null`. However usually there is no need to check for any of those as no LINQ-method returns `null` as result.

Comment: `db.TableName.ToList().Count` loads the whole database table into memory just to get the item-count. Of course that is inefficient. But if you have or need it anyway it's better to use the `List.Count` poperty instead of using a separated `Count()` query. Also, `someThing.ToList()` **never** returns `null` but an empty list.

Comment: As an aside, `.Count()` will cause the program to enumerate the entire collection. If all you want is to check whether it's empty, use `.Any()`, which will return as soon as it's counted more than zero - ie. after the first object. With big collections, or if it comes after complex operations (like big `.Where()` or `.Select()` calls), this is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

`SomeQueriable` represents an expression tree until you call `ToList`. When you evaluate `SomeQueriable == null`, you are checking to see if the expression tree is `null`. When you evaluate `SomeQueriable.ToList() == null` you are checking whether to see if the result of the query is `null` which, I don't think it ever will be - I *think* it returns an empty collection which is more idiomatic.

Calling `SomeQueriable.Count()` is null-safe so long as `SomeQueriable` is definitely assigned. Just like with any other variable, if it has the possibility to be `null`, add a null check or use the [null-conditional operator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825488/New-Features-in-Csharp-Null-Conditional-Operator) in C# 6.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to check for null, as you can see in the [source code here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1491):

```
    public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such case when you would receive `SomeQueriable.ToList()` equals `null`. This method always returns a collection. Even if you forgot assigning `SomeQueriable` to some value - you would get `NullReferenceException`.

In my opinion, such checks on null reference should be elimited as much as possible during development so your code can be read more clearly.

Therefore you should make sure that you've assigned `SomeQueriable` with some query and if you want to check if you have received any results - please use `.Any()`

```
if (SomeQueriable.Any())
```

But note that deferred execution could be sometimes tricky.
In case you need search results and check on their existance - it is better to execute query, for instance by calling `.ToList()` and then do your checks:

```
var results = SomeQueriable.ToList();
var isAnyResults = results.Any();
```

Because if you execute other way around (firstly `.Any()` and then `.ToList()`) - I will end up with executing the same query twice.